# How to delay a $httprequest?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to to delay my $http call like this:

```
 githubService.getUserEvents = function getUserEvents() {
      return $timeout(
      $http.get(ANGULAR_EVENTS).then(function (eventsData) {
        return _.map(eventsData.data, function (data) {
          return {
            type: data.type,
            user: data.actor.login,
            avatarUrl: data.actor.avatar_url,
            createdOn: data.created_at,
            repo: data.repo.name
          };
        });
      }),
        5000);
      };
```

When I run this it does not seem to perform the delayed request and I cannot see any errors in the chromeconsole? See also here [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/zuwidadica/edit?html,js,console,output)

How can I call a delayed $http request without using an interceptor?

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/zuwidadica/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: From your jsbin : `Error: $timeout is not defined`

Comment: I fixed it still does not work?

Comment: put `return $timeout(` on the same line. Your code actually does return `undefined`, and the $timeout is never reached. Accepted answer did the job because he solved that issue by removing the return on top of your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleted answer had this right I think, you do need a deferred since you can't return from the $timeout, also as comment indicated needed to inject $timeout service.

```
githubService.getUserEvents = function getUserEvents() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $timeout(
  function(){
    $http.get(ANGULAR_EVENTS).then(function (eventsData) {

    deferred.resolve(_.map(eventsData.data, function (data) {
      return {
        type: data.type,
        user: data.actor.login,
        avatarUrl: data.actor.avatar_url,
        createdOn: data.created_at,
        repo: data.repo.name
      };
    }));
  })

  },2000);
  return deferred.promise;

};
```

Looks like I went over the public API limit here but should work.

---

***EDIT***
Per comments tried with just returning the $timeout promise and it does seem to work here (didn't seem to work when I tried that at first yesterday even after fixing the $timeout, so not sure what was wrong but here's the function working without making an extra deferred object)

```
githubService.getUserEvents = function getUserEvents() {

  return $timeout(function(){
    return $http.get(ANGULAR_EVENTS).then(function (eventsData) {

    return _.map(eventsData.data, function (data) {
      return {
        type: data.type,
        user: data.actor.login,
        avatarUrl: data.actor.avatar_url,
        createdOn: data.created_at,
        repo: data.repo.name
      };
    });
  })

  },2000);
};
```

Still I have to stand by my point in the comments.  So long as you are aware making your own defer is going to have some overhead and you are resolving whatever without going through the whole promise chain then I don't see an issue with doing it the first way (and I find it easier to understand).  However just for clarification the $timeout promise does resolve with the value returned from the function it triggers (this makes sense but the docs made it sound as though $timeout resolved the moment the function was triggered not when it was complete... didn't get to the return part of the docs though tbh).

Comment: Why do I need to use $q here? Is $http not asynchronous already?

Comment: It is but the problem is getting a reference to the promise it creates outside of the $timeout I don't believe you can get the value out by returning it in the $timeout since the timeout resolves when the function is fired but documentation doesn't say anything really about chaining with it or using a promise within the $timeout... only other option I can think of is initializing an empty object before the $timeout and use angular.copy to populate it with the promise from the $http call but seems like 6 of one half dozen of the other.

Comment: Using $q to explicitly create a new defer we can return that and resolve it whenever whatever async thing completes.

Comment: I deleted my answer when I saw that $timeout already returns a promise. The code posted by OP should already work. There was an error with dependency injection on his code, there was another error because he did not use "use strict", so the code returned sooner than it should.

Comment: I'm sorry to have down-voted you, but I sincerely think using a deferred here is an anti-pattern. returning `$timeout()` should work the same way you added your deferred. This answer could be misleading to other users.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout#$timeout-returns

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe no problem on the down vote, but I'm not sure I agree on the "anti pattern".  An anti pattern is something you should avoid because it will lead to a bad system design, as opposed to a positive design pattern which is a structuring of code that is conducive to solving a particular problem.  I believe "anti-pattern" is thrown around a lot for things which people believe to not be 100% correct, but those things are just wrong not an "anti-pattern".  Anyhow semantics aside I understand you're saying the $timeout should resolve with the return value.

Comment: All that said I have to say using a defer instead of having 5 return statements in this function seems a lot simpler to me in either case.  I will still try to test that one out here (with all the returns) to verify it isn't some problem with the $timeout returns and to clarify on that.

Comment: Thank you for the update (downvote removed). I explained the error as a comment on the question. Your first solution is an anti-pattern because now, the coder needs to handle manually the error, and will probably forget to do so at some point. returning `$timeout` directly avoids this mistake to be done. Also, there is no need to use a `return` if you use lambda expressions

Comment: if `return` annoys you too much, you can still write your code like the following : https://jsfiddle.net/Lq9556y1/3/

Comment: Right but that syntax only works with babel compiling it for browsers that don't have built in support yet and the point still stands that it's easy to accidentally not return something there and it's hard to trace what's going on exactly.  I see the point about it being wrong to not have the error handled, but could just modify the answer to have .error(deferred.error) and would basically mitigate the problem.  Guess my point is the function is async so using a deferred when it make sense doesn't seem to be an issue to me (as you said assuming you handle/propagate the error)